# Transfer commits from remote to other remote

Tags: git

I have git repository with two remotes. Origin and edgebox.

edgebox/master is three commits ahead otherwise both remotes have the same commits. Hashs are also same in both remotes.

My question is how transfer those three commits from edgebox to origin?

I know I can use `cherry-pick` or `merge`. But is any way to transfer those commits? Ideally with original hahs from edgebox.

Comment: `fetch` to download commits from remote repository. `push` to upload commits to remote repository. `cherry-pick` and `merge` is not about transferring commits, but about crafting new ones in local repository. `git fetch edgebox master; git push origin FETCH_HEAD:master`

Comment: @PetSerAl I need to get those three commits to my origin master. Both remotes I have local. Not on server. So I can use `fetch` and `push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git pull edgebox master
git push origin master
```

Comment: Pleas upvote as well if you are happy with the answer :)